# Querying mongodb collection SpringWebFlux with reactivemongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am developing simple spring webflux demo application with reactive mongodb  and i want to read all data of Employee by name except containing name field  "joe","Sara","JOE","SARA" and i have following code like:

//repository interface

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Employee, String>{
 Flux<Employee> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

//Service class

```
public class EmplyeeService
{

private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public Flux<Employee> findAllByOrganizationName(String name)
 {

        return employeeRepository.findAllByName(name);

    }

 public Flux<String> getAllNameExceptSome(String name)
{
     Employee emp1=new Employee();
     List<Flux<Employee>> emp=Arrays.asList(employeeRepository.findAllByName(name));
     Flux<Flux<Employee>> emp2=Flux.fromIterable(emp)
             .filter(name->name.equalsIgnoreCase("joe"));
     return emp2;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is blocking and not reactive code. The `findAllByName` should reteurn a `Flux`, which you filter diretly and return .

Comment: @M.Deinum,Thank you for your reply and now we have reactive code.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @firegloves,above code not working like what i am looking for like getting name from mongo collection except some name as described in above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unless some particular situations, you should avoid these data structures:

```
List<Flux<Employee>>
Flux<Flux<Employee>>
```

However you are not leveraging Spring Data. You can achieve you result simply changing your repository to:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Employee, String> {

   // this find all Employee except those matching names provided as param
   Flux<Employee> findAllByNameNotIn(List<String> nameList);

   // this find all Employee matching names provided as param
   Flux<Employee> findAllByNameIn(List<String> nameList);
}
```

Invoking this method you will obtain the list of Employee already filtered by name.

Comment: I want to read that data which i left, like in previous example "Joe" and "Sara". i want "Joe" ,"Sara" in separately ?

Comment: you can simply add another method without `Not` keyword. I edited my answer